# Fetch select list value in javascript

Tags: javascript, list, select

I have the select list in the html page as follows:

```
<select onchange="storePolishType('/p/','b',this.value );" class="drop_down1">

<option value="12">Margin2&ndash;Sawed Margin </option>     
<option value="13">Polished-Sawed Back Polished </option>       
<option value="13">Polished-Steeled Back Polished </option>     
<option value="13">Polished&ndash;All Polished </option>        
<option selected="selected" value="11">Sawed-All Polished </option>     

</select>
```

I want to pass value e.g. 11 and value between option tag e.g. "Sawed-All Polished" to the storePolishType javascript function. I don't know how to pass this two values.
    please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you want is:

```
<select onchange="storePolishType(this.value,this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)" class="drop_down1">
```

this will pas the value (eg, 11) and the text (eg, "Sawed-All Polished ") to a function `storePolishType`

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/QFtPG/